# It is possible to prove that two private keys are related?

Tags: public-key, zero-knowledge-proofs

Say Alice owns two keypairs: ($Pub_1$, $Priv_1$) and ($Pub_2$, $Priv_2$).

The pair ($Pub_1$, $Priv_1$) is pretty mundane.

$Priv_2$ was intentionally created by Alice by concatenating $Priv_1$ and the word "banana" (and then she derived $Pub_2$ out of $Priv_2$ the usual way).

Bob knows the public keys.

In *any* asymmetric key algorithm, is it possible for Alice to prove that $Priv_2$ = $Priv_1$ + "banana"? — without revealing the private keys?

Comment: Apple did this for diversifying and anonymity as [twin diversify](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/86073/18298)

Comment: @knaccc The problem is described [here](https://greendrake.info/publications/trusted-anon-identity). You're very welcome to comment on it and make suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you use Curve25519, which has a well-known generator point $G$ which forms a cyclic group of size $\ell$. Valid scalars (private keys) are usually expressed as unsigned little-endian 32-byte sequences.

The ASCII bytes of $\texttt{banana}$ interpreted as a little-endian number is  $107126708920674$.

If you append the ASCII bytes of $\texttt{banana}$ to a 32-byte (256-bit) little-endian private key, what you are mathematically doing is adding $x$ where $x = 107126708920674 \cdot 2^{256}$. Because this private key will exceed the group size $\ell$, an elliptic curve library will only accept it as a private key after it has been reduced $mod\ \ell$.

Therefore the concatenation with $\texttt{banana}$ means you have $priv_2 = priv_1 + x\ mod\ \ell$.

Anyone can easily observe that $pub_2 == pub_1 + x \cdot G$, which could only have happened if you had either added $x$ to $priv_1$, or added $x + n \cdot \ell$ for some value of $n$.

Comment: First, a word is not a good randomizer. 2. Since ECDSA doesn't hash the private key as EdDSA, Alice can create a signature with the other key by only using the word banana ( need some real validation other than my mind). I couldn't see a great threat, however, one should be very careful while using this simple relation. The Twin Diversify, on the other hand, provides better relations...